# Robotics Mecanum Drive Programming

Tags: python, robotics

I'm currently preparing the coding for our robot for an upcoming robotics competition. I'm trying to set up our robot to do autonomous mode (move without people controlling it) but i have run into a problem. I am able to get the robot to move left, right, forward, backward, etc. (we are using a mecanum drive). While in autonomous, we want it to move forward, and then move sideways AFTER it's completed. We have no problem doing them both at once, but doing one after the other is where we run into troubles. Our current code train is:

```
def autonomous(self):
    for a in range(2):
        zero = 0 #lateral movement (positive is left)
        one = -1 #forward movement (negative is forwards)
        four = 0 #rotation (positive is clockwise)

        #set speed 
        speedFLM    =   four    +   zero    -   one
        speedFRM    =   four    +   zero    +   one
        speedRRM    =   four    -   zero    +   one
        speedRLM    =   four    -   zero    -   one 

        #speed modifier
        speedFLM    =   speedFLM/2
        speedFRM    =   speedFRM/2
        speedRRM    =   speedRRM/2
        speedRLM    =   speedRLM/2

        #set motor output
        self.FLM.set(speedFLM)
        self.FRM.set(speedFRM)
        self.RRM.set(speedRRM)
        self.RLM.set(speedRLM)

        wpilib.Timer.delay(1)
        #reset to zero
        self.FLM.set(0)
        self.FRM.set(0)
        self.RRM.set(0)
        self.RLM.set(0)
```

Comment: seems that you're enabling all motors at the same time. Why don't you enable the relevant ones, use the delay, and then turn them off and enable the other ones?

Comment: You have a loop that does the same thing twice.  It doesn't seem that you have any logic to do one thing and then another.  Instead of a `for` loop, write out the inner logic of the loop twice but change the stuff in the `#set speed` section in the second iteration?

Answer (score -1):

[image]

Here's a reference diagram that helped me when I was programming a mecanum based robot that won the programming skills challenge for the state of California. I don't know much about python as I always used C on my bots but, it seems that your delay is only 1 millisecond, could that be the problem? Hopefully at the least, this diagram will help.